# ¿Existe "Try-catch" en VB 6.1?

Tags: vb6

Estoy toqueteando un programa hecho en VB6, tengo que realizar un control de ejecución por si se generan errores en el siguiente código:

```
Dim shell As Object
Dim RUTA As String
RUTA = misGlobales.PathReports & "\SLG_Invocador.exe"
Set shell = CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
shell.Run "cmd /C " & RUTA & " " & guidPedido, 0, True
```

Alguna idea de como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Existe una llamada a `ON Error`, no se si es lo que estés buscando, puedes ver está liga, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement

Comment: No, no existe,debes usar `on error goto..` @HammerffallBK, en enlace que has puesto se refiere a vb.net si no me equivoco

Comment: fua! volver a la epoca COBOL hahahah  okey, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente ya que no existe `Try...Catch` en V6

```
Dim sMsg As String

On Error Goto ErrHandler

' todo tu codigo aqui

Exit Function

ErrHandler:
sMsg = "Error #" & Err.Number & ": '" & Err.Description & "' from '" & Err.Source & "'"
GoLogTheError sMsg
```

Esto lo vi hace relativamente poco tiempo en este post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091787/vb6-how-to-catch-exception-or-error-during-runtime

Comment: Yo quitaría el `GoLogTheError sMsg` de ese código, ya que no tienes la función a la que hace referencia. Por lo demás,buena respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te han mencionado todos, no existe un clausula `TRY..CATCH`, al menos tal como la podemos conocer de otros lenguajes. Lo que sí existe en todas las versiones de Visual Basic hasta la v6, en VbScript y Vba, es un manejador de Errores, con la clausula `ON Error` que con un poco de trabajo permite hacer varias cosas y en esto quiero profundizar en mi respuesta, veamos:

- **`On Error GoTo #línea`**: Establece que a partir de la siguiente instrucción, hasta el final de la rutina o función o hasta el próximo `ON Error` cualquier error capturado hará que la ejecución continue en la línea indicada. La línea no necesariamente tiene que ser un número como antiguamente tenía el lenguaje `Basic`, sino una `etiqueta`, por ejemplo `ErroHandler:` (notar los `:`). Esta línea que establece nuestro manejador de errores tiene que estar dentro de la rutina o función: el `GOTO` no tiene forma de "salir" de la rutina desde dónde se lo invoca.
- **`On Error Resume Next`**: Como su nombre lo indica, captura el error y hace que la ejecución continue con la siguiente instrucción. A los efectos prácticos, no se muestra ningún error y la ejecución continua.
- **`On Error goto 0`**: Una forma algo extraña para indicar que queremos quitar el manejador de errores actual.

Como demostración de esto:

```
Sub Test()

    ' CATCH1 muestra el error y retorna la ejecución a la siguiente linea
    On Error GoTo CATCH1
    a = 1 / 0

    ' Quitamos el manejador de errores CATCH1 (actual), dejamos que VB haga lo que le parezca
    On Error GoTo 0
    a = 1 / 0

    ' CATCH2 muestra el error y finaliza la función/rutina
    On Error GoTo CATCH2
    a = 1 / 0

    ' Sin ningún manejador de errores específico, simplemente continuamos a la siguiente línea
    On Error Resume Next
    a = 1 / 0

    Exit Sub

CATCH1:
    MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & ": '" & Err.Description & "' from '" & Err.Source & "'"
    Resume Next

CATCH2:
    MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & ": '" & Err.Description & "' from '" & Err.Source & "'"
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Por las dudas, si no se deduce del código, en cualquier momento de la ejecución solo puede haber un único manejador de errores activo o ninguno.